# C code with several conditional statements giving an unexpected result

Tags: c

I'm trying to adapt a C program on reinforcement learning, https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/code/pole.c, to Python to participate in the [OpenAI Gym](https://gym.openai.com/). I've copied the `get_box` function into a separate test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_box(float x, float x_dot, float theta, float theta_dot);

int main() {

    int box;
    box = get_box(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01);

    printf("The value of box is : %x\n", box);

    return 0;
}

#define one_degree 0.0174532    /* 2pi/360 */
#define six_degrees 0.1047192
#define twelve_degrees 0.2094384
#define fifty_degrees 0.87266

int get_box(x,x_dot,theta,theta_dot)
float x,x_dot,theta,theta_dot;
{
  int box=0;

  if (x < -2.4 ||
      x > 2.4  ||
      theta < -twelve_degrees ||
      theta > twelve_degrees)          return(-1); /* to signal failure */

  if (x < -0.8)                box = 0;
  else if (x < 0.8)                box = 1;
  else                             box = 2;

  if (x_dot < -0.5)                ;
  else if (x_dot < 0.5)                box += 3;
  else                         box += 6;

  if (theta < -six_degrees)            ;
  else if (theta < -one_degree)        box += 9;
  else if (theta < 0)              box += 18;
  else if (theta < one_degree)         box += 27;
  else if (theta < six_degrees)        box += 36;
  else                         box += 45;

  if (theta_dot < -fifty_degrees)   ;
  else if (theta_dot < fifty_degrees)  box += 54;
  else                                 box += 108;

  return(box);
}
```

which I call `scratch.c`. If I compile this program with `gcc scratch.c -lm` and run it with `./a.out`, I get the following printed output:

```
The value of box is : 55
```

However, if I go through the conditional statements manually I would expect to get 1 + 3 + 27 + 54 = 85, which is also what I get with my Python program. Why does the program print 55?

Comment: Is this a submission to an obfuscation contest? Much of the problem lies in the idiosyncratic indentation style.

Comment: #define values not being in capital letters, no brackets after conditional statements, no parenthesis around all the conditions when there are multiple conditions in an if/else if... Not sure I want to try understanding that piece of code.

Comment: Old-style K&R function definitions didn't support `float` parameters. Instead `double` parameters were passed, which were then cast down. The use of `float` instead of  `double` in your prototype is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd do a `printf("%d\n", box)` instead of `printf("%x\n", box)` you'll get the decimal value printed. 0x55 = 5*16 + 5 = 85

Answer (score -1):

Because your output getting converted to hexadecimal number. If you convert 55 to decimal, then it is equivalent of 85.